# Solr query that inherently boost items based on tags associated with items

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

Consider the items indexed with 3 fields : title, description and tags.
Is there a way in which solr automatically queries against the tags field based on the search term to boost items matching the tags?

Item 1 (Title: AB, Description: This is an A & B item, tags: A,B)

Item 2 (TItle: ABC, Descrption: This is an A &B & C item, tags: A,B,C)

So now I want to search for "B C" such that it gives me item2 as the top result based on the tags, so the search should boost item2 after evaluating the tags field.
Is there a way in which solr automatically queries against the tags field based on the search term to boost items matching the tags without doing the query time boosting manually on a field?

Comment: You'll have to expand your question - it's hard to say what you actually want to do.

Comment: @MatsLindh Added more info

Answer (score 0):

Solr will automatically order the results by relevance, which includes matching as many terms as possible. If you need to search against multiple fields or to give priority to a specific field, it can all be configured through disMax/eDisMax and its [qf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theqf(QueryFields)Parameter) parameter.